# Starting to draw using a class

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

I have to draw a flower("cvijet" in Croatian) using a class. Here's the code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Cvijet.h"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(400, 400), "Hello, SFML world!");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    Cvijet cvijet(&window);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        cvijet.draw();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is how am I supposed to start drawing(.draw() starts drawing but nothing happens if this line doesn't work), using this line:

```
Cvijet cvijet(&window);
```

It takes a pointer to window. I have implemented the constructor in .h file like this:

```
Cvijet(sf::RenderWindow *window);
```

How is this supposed to work? How am I supposed to implement it in .cpp file?
I really don't know how to explain this well since I don't know what the line is supposed to do, so sorry if the question is not well put.

Looking forward to some help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a different approach. SFML even provides base classes to achieve something like this the easy way: `sf::Drawable` and `sf::Transformable`.

A minimal class implementing the virtual members looks like this:

```
class Flower : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable {
public:
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const {
        // Apply the transform and draw our flower
    }
};
```

So you'll just have to fill the blanks in a way that makes sense and essentially draws your flower.

The short version for `draw()`:

- Apply your transform (this is optional but allows you to call `setPosition()` and similar members).
- Draw your custom shapes, polygons, etc.

Sounds easy? Yes, because it is.

If you want to try on your own, stop reading now, give it a spin. If you still can't figure it out, continue for a simple example. If you do, please try to understand the code rather than just copying everything and be done.

---

For this example I'm juts going to use a few instances of `sf::CircleShape`, but you can basically use anything you want. Simple shapes, textured polygons, sprites, etc. it's always the same.

Rather than going step by step, here's a full example doing this:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

class Flower : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable {
private:
    std::vector<sf::CircleShape> mParts;

public:
    Flower(sf::Color color, unsigned int petals = 8, float centerRadius = 10, float petalRadius = 10) :
        mParts(petals + 1) // Resize the vector for all our plant parts
    {
        // Setup the flower's center
        mParts[0].setRadius(centerRadius);
        mParts[0].setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
        mParts[0].setOrigin(centerRadius, centerRadius);
        mParts[0].setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);
        mParts[0].setOutlineThickness(1);

        // No petals? Avoid a division by 0
        if (!petals)
            return;

        // Determine the angle between the individual petals
        float delta = 2 * 3.1415 / petals;

        // Iterate over all petals and set them up
        for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= petals; ++i) {

            // Using a reference here for readability
            sf::CircleShape &petal(mParts[i]);

            petal.setRadius(petalRadius);
            petal.setFillColor(color);
            petal.setOrigin(petalRadius + (petalRadius + centerRadius) * std::sin(i * delta), petalRadius + (petalRadius + centerRadius) * std::cos(i * delta));
            petal.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);
            petal.setOutlineThickness(1);
        }
    }

    void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const {

        // Apply our own transform (from sf::Transformable)
        states.transform *= getTransform();

        // Draw the parts
        for (const sf::CircleShape &part : mParts)
            target.draw(part, states);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(256, 256), "Flowers");

    Flower flower1(sf::Color::Red, 5, 20, 20);
    flower1.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(75, 75));
    Flower flower2(sf::Color::Blue, 8, 10, 10);
    flower2.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(200, 100));

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        // Your typical event loop
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Draw and display our flowers
        window.clear();
        window.draw(flower1);
        window.draw(flower2);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The resulting program will show a window like this:

[image: Example Screenshot]

Note that this isn't the most perfect solution (since we're using several drawing calls per flower), but depending on your use case etc. this should be more than sufficient.

---

To still do the original idea (since it's obviously a requirement), you'd do something like this:

```
class Cvijet {
private:
    sf::RenderWindow *mWindow;
    std::vector<sf::CircleShape> mParts;
public:
    Cvijet(sf::RenderWindow *window) : mWindow(window) {
        // Setup mParts similar to the example above
    }

    void draw() const {
        sf::RenderStates state;
        // Apply the proper transform for the flower position

        // Draw the flower parts
        for (const sf::CircleShape &part : mParts)
            mTarget->draw(part, state);
    }
}
```

Splitting header and implementation: Don't worry about that for now. Implement the class in your header only, which shouldn't be a problem as long as it's not used in multiple other files.

Once that's done and working, you can just move the implementation to its own cpp file. The latest snippet would become something like this (I'm omitting headers, include guards etc. for simplicity):

**cvijet.hpp**

```
class Cvijet {
private:
    sf::RenderWindow *mWindow;
    std::vector<sf::CircleShape> mParts;
public:
    Cvijet(sf::RenderWindow *window);
    void draw() const;
}
```

**cvijet.cpp:**

```
#include "cvijet.hpp"

Cvijet::Cvijet(sf::RenderWindow *window) : mWindow(window) {
    // Setup mParts similar to the example above
}

void Cvijet::draw() const {
    sf::RenderStates state;
    // Apply the proper transform for the flower position

    // Draw the flower parts
    for (const sf::CircleShape &part : mParts)
        mTarget->draw(part, state);
}
```

Comment: I don't have a problem with drawing, it's easy as you have said.
The problem is I have to do it this way and draw function shouldn't take any parameters. This is a template I was given that i *HAVE* to use. So if anyone knows how to make it work that would be really helpful!
Btw. Mario thanks for the post, you spared me some time going through tutorials!

Comment: @Joka Ah! So in this case you should show us your full class and what you've done so far, because we can't determine why it's not drawing without seeing it.

Comment: unfortunately I don't know how to implement the class :(. The only thing I did was to start the constructor. Sorry I have only been programming for 3 months now and I just started learning about the classes/structures. Do you have any idea how to implement it?

Comment: @Joka I've added an implementation using the approach/signature from your original question.

Comment: sorry man but I still don't understand. What do you mean by: // Setup mParts similar to the example above. I can't connect it with the example above.
I can understand if you don't want to answer, but please do :D

Comment: this is what I tried, and for some reason it doesn't draw:

`Cvijet::Cvijet(sf::RenderWindow *window) { 

 sf::CircleShape shape(50);
 shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 250, 50));
 shape.setOutlineThickness(10);
 shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(250, 150, 100));
 shape.setPosition(10, 50);

 window->draw(shape);
}`

Comment: Did it! I just had to copy window loop from main!
Thank you for everything!!